# GIT, source tree: Deleting a character shows as whole line deletion and adding

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to git.I am using source tree as my GIT client.
Even if I remove/change a single character in a file while committing it shows as line is deleted and same line with changed character as if I have added a whole new line.
Isn't it supposed shows only change that has happened? Or Am I asking too much of git ?

Comment: that is how GIT calculates differences (line by line).

Comment: Maybe https://idnotfound.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/word-by-word-diffs-in-git/ is of interest...

Comment: so any small change in a line, like deleting a . (dot) has to be resulted as deleting and adding a new line ? @Dennis

Comment: So GIT is a line based diff. Will try  that thanks for pointing to right direction.@larsks. SVN is a word bsed / characted based version control which is lot more easier to handle when mergin or resolving conflits.

Answer (score 0):

Git actually can show you the word diffs; simply pass `--color-words` to `git diff`. Unfortunately, SourceTree does not have that option, so you need to use the command line or gitk.